# how to webscrape from a site with checkbox with multiple choice

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would like to webscrape from this [site](https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche). I know how to webscrape without filter (here is the code) but how to get only the data with "Catégorie de produit" [selection here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tkm4.jpg) selected for example ?

I mean how can I get only a subset of the data which is selected via the category product ("catétgorie de produit")

I suppose I have to use selenium but how to adapt my code ?

Any help will be helpful

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

import concurrent.futures


# Récupération liste de fonds 
def fonds_quantalys(start, length=1_000):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    data = {'columns[0][name]': 'ID_Produit',
            'columns[1][name]': 'cTypeFinancialItem',
            'columns[2][name]': 'cClasseFinancialItem',
            'columns[3][name]': 'sTypeFinancialObject',
            'columns[4][name]': 'checkbox',
            'columns[5][name]': 'sNom',
            'columns[6][name]': 'sURL',
            'columns[7][name]': 'sNomManager',
            'columns[8][name]': 'sNomTypeFinancialObject',
            'columns[9][name]': 'sGroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic',
            'columns[10][name]': 'sGroupeCat_rng1',
            'columns[11][name]': 'sCodeISIN',
            'columns[12][name]': 'nVL',
            'order[0][column]': '5',
            'order[0][dir]': 'asc',
            'start': start,
            'length': length
            }
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(requests.post('https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche/Data', 
                                        headers=headers, 
                                        data=data)
                          .json()['data'])
        return df
    except:
        pass

def list_fonds(urls, max_workers=None):
    dfs = []
    with tqdm(total=len(urls)) as progress: 
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
            # Submit the tasks to the executor and store the future objects
            futures = [executor.submit(fonds_quantalys, url, length=length_url) for url in urls]

            # Gather the results from the completed futures
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                df = future.result()
                dfs.append(df)
                progress.update(1)

    # Concatenate all dataframes into one
    df = pd.concat(dfs)
    return df

length_url = 1_000
df_list_fonds = list_fonds(np.arange(0, 100_000, length_url)).drop_duplicates('sCodeISIN')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How scrape a page with checkbox with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283020/how-scrape-a-page-with-checkbox-with-scrapy)