# Clicking on a hidden button in Python using Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I have a button that looks like this:

```
<a id="bRegister" class="button bRegister disabled" onclick="void(0);">Register</a>
```

The button gets enabled once a previous checkbox is checked. How do I click on the button? I am using Python with Mechanize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox input using python mechanize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833868/checkbox-input-using-python-mechanize)

Comment: ^ not really Malik.. I believe hes talking about something that was unclickable being clicked after an event happens.

Comment: That's right. The button get's enabled after the previous checkbox is checked.

Comment: You can re-enable the button and proceed as usual, no?

Comment: The button is hidden. Let me give a little more context. 
<input type="hidden" name="register" value="Register">
<a id="bRegister" class="button bRegister" onclick="void(0);">Register<a id="bRegister" class="button bRegister disabled" onclick="void(0);">Register</a></a>